# Exponential map-Analytic Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Given a real analytic Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ (with analytic Riemannian metric), is the exponential map also analytic everywhere? and Why?

Comment: The exponential map arises from the solution of different equations, and analytic ODEs have analytic solutions.

Comment: The exponential map is analytic wherever it is defined (since you do not assume completeness of the metric). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Kowalevski_theorem